# JTable auto-update help

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

Greetings,

I have been understanding how DefaultTableModel will work on my problem.
I had this JTable which already has the data from a query from my data using JDBC - MySQL.
I the role is that the index0 of the JTable always displays the primary key.
And there will always be an empty row at the end two-dimensional object array where the data of the cell will be retrieved.

As of now, I included in the model a setValueAt method which triggers a fireCellUpdated().
It worked but the downside is that the data would display on the JTable but is changed on the array.
How could I resolve this?

Your response is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your problem if you change the array the display should match since your array is driving the model.

Comment: When I check the array, the changes were there. But it won't display on the JTable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I check the array, the changes were there. But it won't display on the JTable

You should never update the array directly. The array is used to populate the data in the DefaultTableModel when you create the model. The DefaultTableModel stores the data in a Vector of Vectors so all the data is copied from the Array to the model. After that all updates must to done directly to the TableModel.

Comment: Not automatically - you'd have to do it manually.  As camickr said, the array is effectively ignored once the `DefaultTableModel` is created.  If you want to use the array as the real source of the data then make your own table model by extending `AbstractTableModel`.  It's not all that difficult - see [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for details.

Comment: Ok. I'll remodel the model then... I'll update once I have accomplished the topic.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your data model contains additional information that's not intended for display. [`DefaultTableModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) may be a little awkward for this. In the alternative, your might want to consider [`AbstractTableModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html), which should make it easier to expose only certain portions of the data to your `JTable`. There are examples in the article [*How to Use Tables: Creating a Table Model*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) and [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table).

Comment: I'll try to remodel the JTable.